# SQLAlchemy: Update table structure

Tags: python, sql-server-2012, sqlalchemy

I created the table on the server using SQLALchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, String, MetaData

engine = create_engine('mssql://server/database?driver=SQL+Server&trusted_connection=yes')
meta = MetaData() 
table = Table('test17', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String('255'))
)

metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Then I connected to this database using SSMS 2012 and added a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE test17 ADD age INT NULL
```

How do I tell using SQLALchemy that a new column appears in the table?

I tried to do something like:

```
meta2 = MetaData()
table = Table('test17', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

But in the end I get the same table structure that I defined initially using SQLALchemy.

Comment: I was wrong in the name of the variable a second time. I already have such a variable, but I defined a new one under a different name `meta2`, but used the old one `meta`. Therefore, the columns were the same.

Comment: Normally you'd reflect possible changes in the table structure in your application code as well, and possibly use something like [alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/) to handle migrations.

Comment: You may be interested in SQLAlchemy [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to bind your MetaData to the engine. Create the engine first, then read the metadata from the db using the engine.

```
import sqlalchemy as db
metadata = db.MetaData(bind=engine)
test17 = db.Table('test17', metadata, autoload=True)
```

Comment: what is db in this case? when i do just MetaData(bind=engine), it causes an exception

Comment: oh, sorry, that is sqlalchemy itself. I always import sqlalchemy as db . added it to the answer

Comment: ah ok thanks. im using just core..i noticed after that db is something used when building the model classes